# Why have I to write c - '0' instead of just c?

Tags: c

Hey I can't understand why my code doesn't write when I put just ++ndigit[c] (instead of ++ndigit[c -'0'], then with ++nchar[c] it's ok.

If you have any tuto I'll be really interested !

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int c, i, y, ns;
  int ndigit[10];
  int nchar[26];

  ns = 0;

  for(i = 0; i >= 0 && i<= 9; ++i) {
    ndigit[i] = 0;
  }

  for(y = 'a'; y <= 'z'; ++y) {
    nchar[y] = 0;
  }

  while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if(c == ' ' || c == '\t') {
      ++ns;
    }

    if(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
      ++nchar[c];
    }

    if(c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
     ++ndigit[c];
     //++ndigit[c-'0'];
    }

    if(c == '\n') {
      printf("chiffres: ");
      for(i=0;i<10;++i) {
        printf("%d:%d ", i, ndigit[i]);
      }

      printf("lettres: ");
      for(y='a';y<='z';++y) {
        printf("%d:%d ", y, nchar[y]);
      }
      printf("space: %d\n", ns);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This will be edxplained in any good C book. I'd recommend to read one and not skip chapters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually when you set the variable to `c='0'`, it means that the value of c is now the ascii value of '0' and that is = 48. 
Since you are setting the value of c to 48 but the array size is 10, your code will get a runtime exception because you are trying to access an index that doesn't even exist.

Remember when you use `'0'` it means character. So setting this value to an `int` variable makes the value equals to the ascii value of that character. Instead you can use `c=0` directly.

Comment: Encoding may not be ASCII. The Standard does however guarantee that the characters `'0'` - `'9'` are encoded in sequence. Note that this guarantee does not hold for other characters.

Comment: but i think ascii values are fixed for '0' to '9' and all english alphabets.

Comment: agreed with you :)

Comment: C implementations do not have to use ASCII. Yet it is likely to be the case, or more likely UTF-8 which is a superset of ASCII. Still, for portability one should consider the existence of, e.g., EBCDIC on legacy systems; and who knows what the future may hold.... The sequential requirement on `'0'` - `'9'` is meant to ensure that the subtraction idiom for finding values of digits from characters works regardless of encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Because the character `'4'` (for example) is usually not equal to the integer `4`. I.e. `'4' != 4`.

Using the most common character encoding scheme [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii), the character `'4'` has the value `52`, and the character `'0'` has the value `48`. That means if you do e.g. `'4' - '0'` you in practice to `52 - 48` and get the result `4` as an integer.

Comment: Thx ! I understood.